# I want to remove some part of string from 'this match' to 'another match'

Tags: php, string, replace, trim

I am trying to use the `trim()` function but it's not working as I need.

I have a string like this:

```
"Hello I have this code: This is important code here"
```

I want to remove some part of this string, using matching string value.

Example:

I want to start the match on `'Hello'`

And stop the match on `'code: '`

It's should output: `This is important code here`

Please help me with its solution, thanks.

example of code ----->

```
$string = 'Hello friend, I have problem with some of string operation case; Please help me if you can';
$first_match = 'I have' ;
$second_match = 'case;' ;
$new_string = remove_function($first_match, $second_match, $string);
```

And Now `$new_string = 'Hello friend, Please help me if you can';`
I need such type of out put and looking for that type of `remove_function()`

I hope someone will understand my question :-)

Comment: You sound like Trump, "Hello I have this code: This is important code here" except you've shared no code.

Comment: I did not understand anything. Could you please rephrase your question?

Comment: Would I be right in saying that you will always have a `:` in the string? And also that you want to keep everything in the string that is to the Right of that `:`

Comment: I agree.  Unclear / Too Broad.  This is a vague requirement dump.  How might your  input strings vary? What have you tried?  (This has nothing to do with `trim()`)

Comment: question marked as duplicate without understanding the question !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thats a bit of an ask for `trim()`

Assuming you will always have a colon `:` in the string and you want to keep only what is to the right of that colon, you can do that like this

```
$str = "Hello I have this code: This is important code here";

if ( ($pos = strpos($str, ':')) !== FALSE ) {
    $new_str = substr($str, $pos+2);
}
echo $new_str;
```

RESULT:

```
This is important code here
```

Comment: Ending is defined, but Beginning is not defined isn't it ?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand. Are you saying this is not working for you

Comment: Yes, it's somewhat working, but I need beginning match, and ending match to remove that string. Help me if you understood...